# Best way of getting the longest sequence of even digits in an integer

Tags: python, string, list, integer, sequences

What would be the most efficient way of getting the longest sequence of even digits in an integer in Python? For example, if I have a number 2456890048, the longest sequence should be 0048.

Should the integer be converted to a string to determine the longest sequence? Or should it be converted into the list and then, based on the indexes of each item, we would determine which sequence is the longest? Or is there a more efficient way that I am not aware of ( i am quite new to Python, and i am not sure what would be the best way to tackle this problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `max`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
def solve(strs):
     return max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(strs, key=lambda x:int(x)%2) if not k),
                                                                            key=len)
... 
>>> solve('2456890048') #or pass `str(2456890048)` if you've integers.
['0', '0', '4', '8']
>>> solve('245688888890048')
['6', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8']
```

Here:

```
[list(g) for k, g in groupby('2456890048', key=lambda x:int(x)%2) if not k]
```

returns:

```
[['2', '4'], ['6', '8'], ['0', '0', '4', '8']]
```

Now we can apply `max` on this list(with `key=len`) to get the longest sequence. (Note that in the original code I am using a generator expression with `max`, so the list is not created in the memory.)

Comment: This might not be the most efficient, but it is probably the most conceptually elegant IMO.

Comment: Thank you! With itertools procedure, how would i then go about finding at what index the sequence started in the original number?

Comment: @nanachan Yes, you need to iterate over `enumerate(strs)` for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is one of most efficient way

```
def longest(i):
    curMax = m = 0

    while i != 0:
        d = i % 10 % 2
        i = i / 10
        if d == 0:
            curMax += 1
        else:
            m = max(m, curMax)
            curMax = 0

    return max(m, curMax)

print longest(2456890048)
```

Comment: You can just check `i % 2` instead of `i % 10 % 2`.

Comment: I think OP wants the longest sequence not just its length.

Comment: Yes, what i need is the longest sequence

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all runs of even numbers using a regexp, and find the longest using max.

```
import re

def longest_run(d):
    return max(re.findall('[02468]+', str(d)), key=len)
```

Comment: This was awesome too. But I doubt `re` would be the best choice here.

Comment: I think you meant `def longest_run(s):`.  Otherwise, this won't work.